# How to print the notification content in the terminal - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to print the content of the notification that comes through PHP (topics) How to print the content of the notification in the terminal using Flutter?

code:

```
class PushNotificationService {
  late BuildContext context;

  PushNotificationService({required this.context});

  Future initialise() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('TopicToListen');

    print('firebase_token->initialize===${messaging == null}==');
    iOSPermission();
    print('firebase_token->initialize=///');
    messaging.getToken();
    print('firebase_token->initialize==**');
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
    /* const IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    const MacOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsMacOS = MacOSInitializationSettings();*/

    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
          (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
        /* didReceiveLocalNotificationStream.add(
          ReceivedNotification(
            id: id,
            title: title,
            body: body,
            payload: payload,
          ),
        );*/
      },
    );

    /*const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
            macOS: initializationSettingsMacOS);*/

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    /*flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {
      print("payload*****$payload");
      selectNotificationPayload(payload);
    });*/
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
          (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
        switch (notificationResponse.notificationResponseType) {
          case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotification:
            selectNotificationPayload(notificationResponse.payload!);

            break;
          case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotificationAction:
            print(
                "notification-action-id--->${notificationResponse.actionId}==${notificationResponse.payload}");

            break;
        }
      },
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: backgroundMessage,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      if (message.data != null) {
        var data = message.data;
        var notif = message.notification;
        if (data['type'] == "default" || data['type'] == "category") {
          var title = data['title'].toString();
          var body = data['message'].toString();
          var image = data['image'];
          var payload = data["news_id"];

          if (payload == null) {
            payload = "";
          } else {
            payload = payload;
          }

          if (image != null && image != "") {
            if (notiEnable!) {
              generateImageNotication(title, body, image, payload);
            }
          } else {
            if (notiEnable!) {
              generateSimpleNotication(title, body, payload);

            }
          }
        } else {
          //Direct Firebase Notification
          var title = notif?.title.toString();
          var msg = notif?.body.toString();
          var img = notif?.android?.imageUrl.toString();
          if (notiEnable!) {
            (img != null)
                ? generateImageNotication(title!, msg!, img, '')
                : generateSimpleNotication(title!, msg!, '');
          }
        }
      }
    });

    messaging.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) async {
      bool back = await getPrefrenceBool(ISFROMBACK);
      print("message******$message");
      if (message != null && back) {
        var data = message.data;
        var notif = message.notification;
        if (data['type'] == "default" || data['type'] == "category") {
          var title = data['title'].toString();
          var body = data['message'].toString();
          var image = data['image'];
          var payload = data["news_id"];

          if (payload == null) {
            payload = "";
          } else {
            payload = payload;
          }

          if (image != null && image != "") {
            if (notiEnable!) {
              generateImageNotication(title, body, image, payload);
            }
          } else {
            if (notiEnable!) {
              generateSimpleNotication(title, body, payload);
            }
          }
        } else {
          //Direct Firebase Notification
          var title = notif?.title.toString();
          var msg = notif?.body.toString();
          var img = notif?.android?.imageUrl.toString();
          if (notiEnable!) {
            (img != null)
                ? generateImageNotication(title!, msg!, img, '')
                : generateSimpleNotication(title!, msg!, '');
          }
        }
        setPrefrenceBool(ISFROMBACK, false);
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      print("message******$message");
      if (message.data != null) {
        var data = message.data;
        var notif = message.notification;
        if (data['type'] == "default" || data['type'] == "category") {
          var title = data['title'].toString();
          var body = data['message'].toString();
          var image = data['image'];
          var payload = data["news_id"];

          if (payload == null) {
            payload = "";
          } else {
            payload = payload;
          }

          if (image != null && image != "") {
            if (notiEnable!) {
              generateImageNotication(title, body, image, payload);
            }
          } else {
            if (notiEnable!) {
              generateSimpleNotication(title, body, payload);
            }
          }
        } else {
          //Direct Firebase Notification
          var title = notif?.title.toString();
          var msg = notif?.body.toString();
          var img = notif?.android?.imageUrl.toString();
          if (notiEnable!) {
            (img != null)
                ? generateImageNotication(title!, msg!, img, '')
                : generateSimpleNotication(title!, msg!, '');
          }
        }

      }
      setPrefrenceBool(ISFROMBACK, false);
    });
  }

  void iOSPermission() async {
    await messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

  //when open dynamic link news index and id can used for fetch specific news
  Future<void> getNewsById(
    String id,
    String index,
  ) async {
    var param = {
      NEWS_ID: id,
      ACCESS_KEY: access_key,
      // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
      USER_ID: CUR_USERID != null && CUR_USERID != "" ? CUR_USERID : "0",
      LANGUAGE_ID: CUR_LANGUAGE_ID
    };

    var apiName = getNewsByIdApi;
    http.Response response = await http
        .post(Uri.parse(apiName), body: param, headers: headers)
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: timeOut));
    var getdata = json.decode(response.body);

    String error = getdata["error"];

    if (error == "false") {
      var data = getdata["data"];

      List<News> news = [];

      news = (data as List).map((data) => new News.fromJson(data)).toList();

      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => NewsDetails(
                model: news[0],
                index: int.parse(index),
                id: news[0].id,
                isDetails: true,
                news: [],
              )));
    }
  }

  selectNotificationPayload(String? payload) async {
    if (payload != null && payload != "") {
      debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
      getNewsById(payload, "0");
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I searched so much in the firebase documentation and couldn't find anything that could help me with the issue.
I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted the following line into the **main.dart** file
And I got the notification content in the terminal.
Hope this helps people in the future

```
  Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.notification?.body}');
}
```